# RXJava - running multiple observables after another (like concat, but with onCompleted for each observable)

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Is there some way to achieve following:

I have 3 observables of the type `Observable<MyData>`. What I want is following:

- run the first observable
- observe the `onCompleted` of the first observable
- run the second observable
- observe the `onCompleted` of the second observable
- run the third observable
- observe the `onCompleted` of the third observable

This can be done with `concat` but then I only will be able to observe the last `onCompleted`.

**Ugly solution**

I know, I can achieve that, if I just start the next obersvable from the `onCompleted` event of the former one.

**Question**

Is there any other way to achieve this with even with an arbitrary number of observables? I want to avoid chaining this all together from the `onCompleted` event, as this looks really ugly and the deeper the chaining goes the less clear it gets...

**Edit - UseCase**

- First, I want to emit the data that represents the data my app had loaded the last time it was started (I will serialise the data to disc) => the reason is, I want a very fast app start all the time
- Then I want a second run of data loading, to load up-to-date data in an empty state
- then I want a third run of data loading to load the missing deeper data of the up-to-date data

I want to constantly update the UI and I want to know, when each level of data loading has finished

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by observing multiple `onCompleted` events? Can you give us an example use case here?

Comment: Edited my question with my use case...

Comment: Hey, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 14):

I hope below code helps.

```
Observable<MyData> observable1 = ...;
Observable<MyData> observable2 = ...;
Observable<MyData> observable3 = ...;

Observable
        .concat(observable1.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable1),
                observable2.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable2),
                observable3.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable3))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( ... );
```

Here is sample methods.

```
void onCompleteObservable1() {
    //do some work
}

void onCompleteObservable2() {
    //do some work
}

void onCompleteObservable3() {
    //do some work
}
```

Comment: I've got a question @nshmura : wouldn't concat call all these observables at the same time? Let's imagine you have some memory intensive work to do in your observables. Calling them all the same time could lead to a massive memory and CPU usage. Is there a way to call them after each other? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HannoGödecke No, the observables are executed serially and each on will only start after the previous one has completed. If one of them fails, the following ones will not be started.

Answer (score 1):

I think [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) could be the answer.
With concatMap you can concatenate observables and subscribe once, so you're code could be something like:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    .concatMap(integer -> Observable.just(integer)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .concatMap(i -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000));
                    return Observable.just(2 * i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Observable.error(e);
                }
            }))
    .subscribe(System.out::println,
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            () -> System.out.println("onCompleted"));
```